why does $\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})+\cos(\frac{\pi}{5})\cos(\frac{2\pi}{5})+\cos(\frac{\pi}{7})\cos(\frac{2\pi}{7})\cos(\frac{3\pi}{7})...=1$
How can you prove that
\begin{align}
& \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) +
\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right)
\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}\right) +
\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{7}\right)
\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)
\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{7}\right)\ldots
\\[2mm] = & \ 1\ ?.
\end{align}
I can see through use of calculators that in general:
$$
\prod_{k = 1}^{n}
\cos\left(\frac{k}{2n + 1}\right) =
\frac{1}{2^{n}}
$$
Why is this the case ?.

Your second question is a duplicate.  Try multiplying $\cos\frac\pi7\cos\frac{2\pi}7\cos\frac{3\pi}7$ by $\sin\frac\pi7$and see if you can simplify it to $\frac18\sin\frac\pi7$

Can you explain how it is a duplicate? I can prove that each term is true up to $n=5$ or $\cos(\pi/11)...\cos(5\pi/11)=2^{-5}$ and probably more if I have time but can't find a generalized solution or method

Just with $\sin\theta\cos\theta =\frac12\sin2\theta$, and $\sin\theta=\sin(\pi-\theta)$, you can start with $\theta=\pi/7$, and keep doubling, hoovering up the cosines as you go, until $\theta$ ends up where it started.  You might need a few different starting thetas to take care of all the cosines, but the number of $1/2$s equals the number of cosines.

This is not a complete answer to the specific question you are asking, but I think it gets you headed in the right direction: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-gazette/article/abs/8862-grandmas-identity/AF41FE95D91E607A1FD4BF313E2664C3

Multiplying $\sin \left( \dfrac {\pi}{2n+1} \right) $ to given $\prod_{k=1}^n \cos \left( \dfrac {k\pi} {2n+1} \right)$ will get you to the value $f(n) \cdot \sin \left( \dfrac {\pi}{2n+1} \right) $ for some $f(n)$.

You can also do it by noting the roots of $x^n-1$ for $n$ odd are of the form $x=\cos{\frac{2k \pi}{n}}+i \sin{\frac{2k \pi}{n}}$. Setting $x=-1$ and then using some basic trig identities is how Humble did it in the linked article.

In case you need a complete answer, I can pose it:
Start with the first term:
$$\cos\frac{\pi}3=\frac 12$$
And again, for the second term:
$$
\cos\frac{\pi}5\cos\frac{2\pi}5=\frac{\sin\frac{\pi}5\cos\frac{\pi}5\cos\frac{2\pi}5}{\sin\frac{\pi}5}
$$
$$
\cos\frac{\pi}5\cos\frac{2\pi}5=\frac 14 \frac{\sin\frac{4\pi}5}{\sin\frac{\pi}5}=\frac14 \frac{\sin(\pi-\frac{\pi}5)}{\sin\frac{\pi}5}=\frac14
$$
And similarly, for the other terms, you can show that:
$$\cos\frac{\pi}7\cos\frac{2\pi}7\cos\frac{3\pi}7=\frac18$$
And this proves your second equation:
$$\prod_{k=1}^n\cos\left(\frac {k\pi}{2n+1}\right)=\frac1{2^n}$$
And therefore, the above expression evaluates to:
$$\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\frac1{16}+\cdots$$
The sum of this infinite series is:
$$
S=\frac{\frac12}{1-\frac12}=1
$$

I feel like this still doesn't explicitly prove that the second equation is true for all n, it only shows that the trend is there. For example, how do you know this is true for n=100? Do you just try reducing it like the others or is there a smart way around?

I do not know any smarter way around, this seems to be the only way...
The equation shows a pattern, show it must hold true for any value of $n$, I guess. The trend acts as the proof actually.
